# How do I compare arrays or box.tuple objects In Tarantool?

Tags: arrays, compare, tarantool

Might be a novice question, but still. How do I compare arrays or box.tuple objects In Tarantool? I need to check if their values are equal?

Answer (score 0):

To compare value please use this code

```
if #a~=#b ret false 
for i=1,#a if a[i]~=b[i] ret false
ret true
```